# Role/Account checking with navigation guards or on each API request

Tags: angular, security, vue.js, single-page-application

Assuming I am using vue, angular or react whome widely support nav guards. Is it better to check a users authentication for teh route they are trying to access in the nav guard before the view is rendered or is it better to go ahead and load the view and check authentication on every ajax call that is being made. Or would it be better to implement both for extra precautions? Currently, a user can put in a different accounts id in the parameters for a route and it will load that accounts given page but will not load its data. I feel like this is prone for an error occurring at somepoint and am starting to wonder about implementing a global navigation guard that will make this check before each render but I am also afraid that it will take away the feel of a single page application by making one wait for authentication before each page loads.

Comment: I would say you should check any permission related part of your code from the navigation guards. It makes no sense to check role during navigation. But in your case, I guess it makes sense. But why not land all users in a specific component and you can do checking and routing from there... either way interesting question, let us know which what you decided to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the ajax calls are all adequately checked for permission then technically you should be fine to serve the html for other accounts without the data. I'm currently working on a project where the html and back-end are on different servers and we are just using authentication on calls to the back-end server. However, access to the site is very limited so it's very unlikely we'll have any users snooping around.

I would say authenticating the ajax calls is a must - only authenticating the routes would be pretty dangerous - so the question becomes should you authenticate both routes and ajax calls or just ajax calls. From there I'd say it's just a question of how safe you want to be. Not authenticating routes potentially leaves you open to snooping users maybe trying to figure out which accounts exist and similar things as well as leaving the door a little wider open if you accidentally leave a vulnerability in your authentication. It really should be safe to just authenticate ajax, but if you want to be especially safe I'd go with both. Then again if you want to be super safe you probably shouldn't be putting the account ids or info in the url.

Comment: You make a great point that came up in discussion. Ajax routes should definitely be checked at least on the backend (comparing the data requested with the roles corresponding with the web token included in the header) and routes should probably also be checked before letting them navigate there cause if something comes up for them then they can make an educated assumption of what is in the database by trying out id's in the URI. Very good point. It is very sensitive information so i think we will probably be going with nav checks, ajax call checks (making sure tokens present) and backend check